# ubuntu mysql install error with php

Tags: ubuntu, mysql

When i try ton install php5-mysql it gives this error

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
php5-mysql: Depends: php5-common (= 5.2.6.dfsg.1-3ubuntu4) but 5.2.6.dfsg.1-3ubuntu4.4 is to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

I tried installing php5-common but it says php5-common is new version

I think i have to install
Code:

```
5.2.6.dfsg.1-3ubuntu4.4
```

but i don't know what that is and how to upgrade it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this - get rid of php and install it from scratch:

```
sudo bash
apt-get remove php5*
# now edit /etc/apt/sources.list and comment out any backports or non-canonical repositories you might have put there
apt-get clean
apt-get update
apt-get install php5-common php5-mysql libapache2-mod-php5
```

Answer (score 0):

That is most likely an Ubuntu bug, which should be reported. As mysql is such a popular package, my guess would be that it will be solved any minute. Try updating your repository now and see if it works.

You should mention which version of Ubuntu you are running. That would help if we need to trace the bug.

Comment: i have ubuntu 9.04 , i have installed mysource matrix on that and it stops working if upgrade the whole OS , is there any other way to fix that , without upgrading the whole OS